# vb.net Replacing (x, y) coordinates in To-DO List Program

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a final project in my VB class and I'm basically allowing the user to create things that they need to do as labels in a to do list and then have them display based on an `InputBox(addUrgency)` where they select between "!", "!!", and "!!!". I want the labels with "!!!" to display at the top and "!" at the bottom. I was playing around with using a do-until loop to check to to see if the index of the `addUrgency` <> the others but I cant add an index to my `label`, obviously...

What's the best way of attacking something like this?

Comment: Going to need significantly more info such as the code you are using, it's output, and the expected output.

Comment: You might want to start by sorting the list by urgency and then display them in that order.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment that we don't know enough, but based on what you've written, I'd create a dictionary where the keys are the to-do tasks and the values are the urgency (number of '!'). Then create and present your labels based on the underlying data. Something like:

```
    Dim todo As New Dictionary(Of String, Byte)
    'populate todo with data here

    For Each kvp In From p In todo Select p Order By p.Value
        'create and present label here
    Next
```